# Porting recursive C struct to Fortran

Tags: c, struct, interop, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

What is the right way to define this recursive C struct in Fortran?

```
struct OPTION {
        char option;
        char *arg;
        struct OPTION *next;
        struct OPTION *previous;
};
```

I've written this Fortran code:

```
module resources
use iso_c_binding
implicit none
   type :: OPTION
      character(c_char) :: option
      character(c_char) :: arg
      type(OPTION), pointer :: next
      type(OPTION), pointer :: previous
   end type OPTION
end module resources
```

This compiles, but I think it is wrong because `bind(c)` in the type definition is missing. If I try to use `type, bind(c) :: OPTION` gfortran blames with `Error: Component 'next' at (1) cannot have the POINTER attribute because it is a member of the BIND(C) derived type 'option' at (2)`.

And If I preserve `type, bind(c) :: OPTION` and remove the `POINTER` attribute I get `Error: Component at (1) must have the POINTER attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   type, bind(c) :: OPTION
      character(c_char) :: option
      character(c_char) :: arg
      type(c_ptr) :: next
      type(c_ptr) :: previous
   end type OPTION
```

C pointers in Fortran aren't really treated as pointers, but as a completely separate type. You'll have to convert them to Fortran pointers by `C_F_POINTER` to get most use out of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use C-type pointers via the `type(c_ptr)` type:

```
module resources
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  type, bind(c) :: OPTION
    character(c_char) :: option
    character(c_char) :: arg
    type(c_ptr) :: next
    type(c_ptr) :: previous
  end type OPTION
end module resources
```

Comment: `next`and `previous`are `type OPTION` not pointer, that is my problem.

Comment: With `type(c_ptr)` you can map all C-pointers independent of their type. As noted by [none_00's post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15486033/1859258), however, you will have to convert them via `C_F_POINTER` to access their fields.